# Is my wireless AP broken?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have TPLink wr741nd provided by my ISP so I cannot check the settings.

Now the problem is I have really bad reception at my desk. I did some tests under same conditions, measuring with inSSIDer3 and Wifi checker form Nirsoft. The first test is with 741's stock antenna which has 5dbi rating. The second one is with bought antenna rated at 15dbi. The router is set to maximum Transmit Power.

```
 AP           Antena         Signal     
----------------------------------------
 TPLink        5dbi          -80dbm/40%
              15dbi          -77dbm/55%
----------------------------------------
 Huawei        3dbi          -65dbm/70%
```

As you can see the change in reception for TPLink is quite small. Next I tried an old (5years in service) Huawei EchoLife HG520i ADSL modem with AP. It has only 3dbi antenna but the increase in reception was quite big.

For the test I have put both devices in same place, both were operating on 802.11g on same channel and the antenna has same orientation (vertical). For measuring I have used notebook, which has antenna integrated into monitor rim. Although I don't think this matters as I'm measuring the relative change, not absolute value.

Does it mean the TPLink is broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ISP replaced my router with new piece and now it works fine. I can only guess what the problem was, but at least the Wifi works now.